# How to logically separate a iteration?

Tags: java

I wanted to logically divide a loop every 4 iterations.
Say, for example, I'm looping a list of filenames in an array 10 times, I wanted to run the first 4 filenames, then do a print statement, again loop the remaining 4, do a print statement, loop the last 2 but don't do a print. In other words, the print statement should not print if the iteration is less than 4. This should be dynamic and it should work for any iteration count (e.g) 167, 282 etc.

Please help.

Comment: Please don't just select random tags in the future, choose only relevant tags to your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ((loopcount != 0) && (loopcount % givenIteration == 0))
  System.out.print("String");
```

Comment: might want to add a check to ignore the first pass when loopcount == 0

Answer (score 0):

Use a int variable that increments at every iteration.  When its value is 4, print what you want, then reset its value

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a count variable to check this.

For example,

```
count = 1;
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
   count++;
   if(count==4){
      System.out.print();
      count =1;
    }

 }
```